# VideoView not able to play video stream of higher bitrate

Tags: android, android-videoview, http-live-streaming

I am trying to play HLS (Http Live Streaming) video stream using android VideoView.

Android VideoView is playing video streams of lower bitrate (bitrate around 200 to 700 kbps) properly, but when i switch from lower bitrate to higher bitrate like 1 mbps or more then video view is not able to play video properly and video gets stuck and only audio is heard.

Is this a issue with video view, i have checked with diff. video streams and i am seeing same results.

Android version: ICS-4.0.4.

Comment: Can you try playing only the higher bitrate (not switching to it during playback)? Also, do you see anything in the android logs? It's certainly possible that the higher bitrate stream is using encoder settings that your device is incapable of decoding.

Comment: thanks for the reply i will check that. but the m3u8 of 1 mbps i have tried on many devices but it fails on every device. so can we conclude it is a issue with VideoView.